# CodeIgniter - Error Number: 1146

Tags: php, codeigniter

Code:

```
<?php 
class Migration_Create_sessions extends CI_Migration {

  public function up()
  {
    //Default codeigniter seesion table
    $fields = array(
      'session_id VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT \'0\' NOT NULL',
      'ip_address VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT \'0\' NOT NULL',
      'user_agent VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL',
      'last_activity INT(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL',
      'user_data text NOT NULL'
    );

    $this->dbforge->add_field($fields);
    $this->dbforge->add_key('session_id', TRUE);
    $this->dbforge->create_table('ci_sessions');
    $this->db->query('ALTER TABLE `ci_sessions` ADD KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)');  
  }

  //Rollback - drop entire table
  public function down()
  {
    $this->dbforge->drop_table('ci_sessions');
  }
}
?>
```

Error:

```
Error Number: 1146
Table 'bma.ci_sessions' doesn't exist
INSERT INTO `ci_sessions` (`session_id`, `ip_address`, `user_agent`, `last_activity`,  `user_data`) VALUES ('', '127.0.0.1', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36', 1404181497, '')
Line Number: 330
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$this->dbforge->create_table('ci_sessions', TRUE);
```

An optional second parameter set to TRUE adds an "IF NOT EXISTS" clause into the definition
This gives:

```
// gives CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ci_sessions
```

Comment: Now worked!!!
    
    database.php
    
    "
    $db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
    $db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
    $db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
    "
    
    change it as
    
    "
    $db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
    $db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
    $db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
    "

Answer (score 0):

Change the following:

```
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
```

By default, it is true.

When changed this to false, migration works.